What is the proper way to use a Viterbi Decoder in continuous mode in Matlab?
I'm trying to replicate the viterbi decoding operation in this example:
openExample('comm/DigitalVideoBroadcastingTerrestrialExample','supportingFile','commdvbt.slx')
It's doing okay, but I noticed that the Inner Decoder (Conv Encode) seems to be performing poorly compared to other blocks.
Example (comparing bits of input to output ):
OFDM Error rate: 1.000000 (makes sense because no two input and output symbols will be exactly the same after noise)
Mapping Error rate: 0.107143
Inner Int Error rate: 0.019761
Inner Dec Error rate: 0.029412
Iteration: 1
...
OFDM Error rate: 1.000000
Mapping Error rate: 0.074625
Inner Int Error rate: 0.003676
Inner Dec Error rate: 0.371936
Iteration: 28288
...
OFDM Error rate: 1.000000
Mapping Error rate: 0.058128
Inner Int Error rate: 0.012408
Inner Dec Error rate: 0.035539
Iteration: [last]
Resultant Error rate [all iterations]: 0.98776
If I use 'trunc' and 'hard' I get better results, but the viterbi decoder still sees consistent error rates between 0.01 - 0.50.
I believe the reason is because I'm somehow not achieving continuity between my iterations.  Can someone show me just an example of the proper way to use the convenc() and vitdec() functions in 'cont' mode?  the input can be something like:
 p = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i = 1:10
[Pseudo-code]
    

    x = (10*(i-1)) + p;

    convencode (x) 

    vitdec(x) in continuous mode

end

Here's what my code sort of looked like:
The input is a random 188 byte packet generated in a for loop.
trellis = poly2trellis(7,[171 133]);                %Trellis for 3/4 encoder
puncpat = [1 0 1 0 1 1]';                           %Puncturing Pattern
packets = 8;
ofdm_symbols = 2; %doesnt matter the size, bigger means more sample size.  I try to keep in multiples of 2


for i =  1: packets*ofdm_symbols + (2244/204)
    [ Some operations]    
    ....
    ....
    %% Inner Coder (Conv Encode)
        msg_encoded(startidx_out:endidx_out) = convenc(bin_interleaved(startidx_in:endidx_in), trellis,puncpat);
    ... 
    ...
    [ Some operations]
    ...
    ...
    %% Inner Decoder (Vit Dec)
        msg_decoded(startidx3_out:endidx3_out) = vitdec(Deinterleaved_packet(end-2175:end)', ...
        trellis,length(msg),'cont','unquant',puncpat);
    ...
    ...
end

I tried using the 'trunc' operation mode which is what obtained for me the best results.  Still, it's obvious that 'trunc' is just going to fill unnecessary 0's in that I don't need, especially when I'm doing all of my coding and decoding packet by packet in one loop.
